How to shift/scroll carousel images 4 at a time rather than existing 1 at a time?
This is regarding 2 carousels in loveofgod.co.in.
They shift/scroll towards left 1 icon at a time.  This is causing user to WAIT more to view all icons in the images.  So i want to shift 4 icons in a batch/at1time so that user gets to view/click all icone in 2-3 seconds itself.
Or, other suggestions so that all icons in the carousels get visible in single screen itself because no user will wait more than 2,3 seconds on this page.  Most users visiting via mobile device.

<div class="gallery">
                <h2>Institutions By Eternal Masters (Click On The Photo)</h2>

                <div class="owl-carousel-wrap owl_2">
                    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                        <div class="item" data-id="000" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                            <img class="lazyOwl" src="2/Srila Prabupada.png" alt="Srila Prabupada">
                        </div>


